# My TeXworks platform is presenting me with \end{document} problems

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\title{text}
\author{text}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[useprefix=true,isbn=false,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{resource.bib}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error? What does log file show?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Minimal example is very important, but in this case we need to know the nature of these 'problems' as well.

Comment: Myself, I get `Package keyval Error: isbn undefined` when I run this code.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine, here. The problem must stem from the contents of your .bib file. Check for errors in it.

Comment: We will need more info to help here: in particular, a list of the files used by LaTeX. Please add `\listfiles` to your input, and edit the resulting `File list` from the `.log` file into the question. Until that happens, we can't hope to answer so I'm closing.